# 先に vs まず vs 最初 as in first?

Tags: word-choice, usage

Like in the context of this sentence: "I wish I could return home first."

I'm thinking まず is more correct, like まず家へ帰ればいいのに。

Is まず the best one to use here?

Comment: What kind of context do you have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず has the nuance of ”first of order”. And it is often followed by ”次に”(next) or ”2番目に”(secondly).

最初に has ”first of all”(I think it's almost the same as まず). And followed by 次に or 2番目に.

先に has ”adding in front of the order from outside them”. And followed by ”その後に”(after that).

But almost no difference in meaning, rather it depends on the collocation. Furthermore, there is also the expression ”まず先に” or ”まず最初に”.

In your situation, I think ”先に” or ”まず先に” is more appropriate. However, your sentences are a little short to judge. The possibility of using different expressions is left to other sentences.